# Linear algebra matrix inverse identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ which is full rank. Is $A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top= I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix? If so how can this be shown?

Note: it may be assumed that the matrix $A$ has full column rank and therefore $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: But in general $A$ and $B$ are not square and so do not have inverses?

Comment: $(A^tA)^{-1}$ may not exist even when $A$ has full rank.

Comment: If $A=(1,0)$ then $A^TA$ is not invertible.

Comment: $A^TA$ is necessarily invertible if we assume $m \geq n$

Comment: @Jim it may be assumed that $A$ has full column rank and therefore $A^\top A $ invertible, right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: For example $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has full column rank and $m \geq n$.

Comment: @Jim if we allow complex entries, then it is more typical to take the complex-transpose, corresponding to the adjoint of a transformation.

Comment: @Jim this question is likely about real matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot happen. Assume $m>n$. Let  $rank(A)=n$.
Then $A^TA \in M_n$ is invertible.

By the properties of the rank
$$
rank(A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T) \le \min(rank(A), rank((A^TA)^{-1}), rank(A^T))=n
$$
and hence
$$
A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T \ne I_m
$$
follows.

To get a feeling for this: consider $A=\pmatrix{1\\0}$. Then $A^TA=\pmatrix{1}$,
and $A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$.