# Projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

If $\mathbf{X}_{n \times K}= \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{x}'_1 \\
       \cdots \\
       \mathbf{x}'_n
     \end{bmatrix}$, then can we say that $\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{x}_k=\mathbf{x}_k$?

I was trying  to show that $(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{x}_k=e_k$, where $e_k$ is a vector with 1 in the k-th entry, and the remaining entries zero. I haven't been successful so far...

Comment: Is $X'$ the transpose of $X$?  If so then [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145215/linear-algebra-matrix-inverse-identity) question may be relevant to you.

Comment: @Jim then what would we need to assume?

Comment: @Jim also it seems a bit different from mine, because I'm not saying anything about X(X'X)^-1X', but of (X'X)^-1X'x_k

Comment: You might want to notice that for a matrix $X$, $Xe_k$ is equal to the $k$th column of $X$. BTW you have some typo somewhere since $X'$ is $K\times n$ and $x_k$ is a $K$-vector so $X'x_k$ does not make sense if $K\neq n$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I agree with you, but I was just using the notation of the book I'm reading, and I think that there are some typos here...

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel if you're interested here my question in more detail. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137478/typos-in-hayashi-econometrics-how-to-understand-this-2sls-as-an-iv-estimator